# red5 service doesn't start on windows

Tags: red5

I installed Red5 5.0.1 on my 64-bit Windows 8 PC. I set IP address as `127.0.0.1` and Port no. as `5080`. It is well installed. But when I go to the services and select start red5 it gives following error message:

```
Windows could not start the Red5 on the local computer. For more information review the System Event Log. If this is non-Microsoft service, contact the service vendor, and refer to service-specific error code 1.
```

I've `JAVA_HOME` set as `C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.6.0_38`. I've 32-bit jdk installed. Red5 was running good earlier, but recently this error is bugging me. I uninstalled and re-installed Red5 again, but this didn't help.

Please help.

Comment: @Robin That wiki is gone now

Comment: The tanuki software dll's don't support win64 in the free version. You can use the red5.bat instead to start the server.

Comment: @asok I got same error how you solved.please help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a port clash with another program it can prevent red5 from running.

Comment: Thanks alex, but there is no port clash.

Answer (score 0):

The page to which I linked above has been removed and my post was putted as a comment, here is what I saved from the wiki and solved my problems (Windows):

- Install Java JDK
- Install Red5
- Try to start the red5 service, if you get error 1067 try the following:

  - in /conf/wrapper.conf add wrapper.java.command=[PATH to]\jre7\bin\java.exe
  - Try starting the service, if you still get an error check if this folder exists (if not, create it!):
    C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\CONFIG\SYSTEMPROFILE\APPDATA\LOCAL\TEMP\

Worked for me.